# Using ConstantForce to simulate wind

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-physics

I'm trying to create a simple platformer. I have triggers set around where if the player collides, ConstantForce is enabled on the player, and the player is pushed in a chosen direction (depending on the trigger). This works relatively well with pushing the player left and right, but where I'm having an issue is when the player is pushed up on the Y axis. The player hovers for a bit but each time he drops, he begins to go lower and lower- eventually exiting the trigger. I want him to maintain a certain height in air unless he Exits the trigger. Increasing ConstantForce only makes him fly higher, decreasing his mass has a similar effect.

```
private ConstantForce getConstantForce;
public GameObject findingThePlayer;
public Vector3 forceDirection = new Vector3();


void Start()

{
   //Getting the ConstantForce component from player
   findingThePlayer = GameObject.Find("pig_test");
   getConstantForce = findingThePlayer.GetComponent<ConstantForce>();


}



void OnTriggerStay()

{



    //turning on the players ConstantForce 
    getConstantForce.enabled = true;

    //we set the vector value in editor, depending which way we want the wind to blow
    getConstantForce.constantForce.force = forceDirection;




}


void OnTriggerExit()

{
    //When player exits trigger, ConstantForce is disabled
    getConstantForce.enabled = false;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hacky way

```
void OnTriggerStay()
{

    //turning on the players ConstantForce 
    getConstantForce.enabled = true;

    //we set the vector value in editor, depending which way we want the wind to blow
    getConstantForce.constantForce.force = forceDirection;

    //Once you reach the height you want, set the body to be kinematic,
    // that way forces will not longer have any effect

    findingThePlayer.rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit()
{
    //When player exits trigger, ConstantForce is disabled
    getConstantForce.enabled = false;

    //And lets make it a physics rigidbody again on exit
    findingThePlayer.rigidbody.isKinematic = false;

}
```

Another Method is to play with the gravity values until it feels right. You can do this by going into Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics